# Error: OAuth 2 parameters can only have a single value: hd

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

Restricted the app to login using OAuth to one domain (say abc.com).
Getting the error with the following steps:

1. Logged in with multiple accounts in a browser on google.
2. On trying to login with a user whose domain is not mentioned, nothing happens(no error message). Try to login with the invalid user twice.
3. Now try to login with a valid user.

On doing that the following error occurs:

> OAuth 2 parameters can only have a single value: hd

In the error stack trace client id is visible. Is that a security risk?

How can this error be fixed?

Comment: I just implemented this functionality and am seeing the same message when I perform the same steps.  Not a very user-friendly workflow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694840/googles-openid-connect-says-oauth-2-parameters-can-only-have-a-single-value-c

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation the hd parameter](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param) is for G Suite, so you are probably repeating the hd parameter, one with the `hd=*` and the other with your hosted domain(s). Also states that you should not rely in this UI optimization to control access to your app.

> In the error stack trace client id is visible. Is that a security
> risk?

None. [It is not a secret](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.2). It is use for debugging purpose.

> How can this error be fixed?

Try to replace the param `hd` instead of just add a new one. In general, this should be done with every param of your request. Also the [OAuth2 documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2) states an `invalid_request` error when you repeat a parameter.