# Google's OpenID Connect says: OAuth 2 parameters can only have a single value: client_id

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

As part of the OpenID Connect (OAuth2 for Login), my application is supposed to request an access token, given a one-time authorization code, via the endpoint `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token`. According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect), this request needs 5 parameters passed to it, `client_id` among them. That is exactly what my application does, using the Perl module `Net::OAuth2`.

Everything has been working fine for several months, but today I was notified that it stopped working. No updates were made to the application code nor the libraries used by it.

The message my application now receives from the server when calling the `token` endpoint is this, in a `400` error response:

```
OAuth 2 parameters can only have a single value: client_id
```

A Google search suggests nobody has ever seen this message before, or lived to tell the tale. There doesn't seem to be a general issue with Google's OpenID Connect (other services based on it are working flawlessly), and the imminent shutdown of the old login protocol doesn't seem relevant.

More testing: removing all parameters except `client_id` causes this error message:

```
Required parameter is missing: grant_type
```

Supplying only `client_id` and `grant_type` produces the original error message again.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on here?

Comment: I experience no such problems; perhaps the issue is caused by `NET::OAuth2` duplicating parameters (i.e. sending client_id twice) and Google tightening up their implementation? You could check by exchanging the `code` manually with a cURL call and/or look at the HTTP post parameters that `NET::OAuth2` sends on the wire.

Comment: @HansZ. good idea, thanks, just added code to dump the generated request. There is no duplication in the query string nor POST body, though. I'm now trying to get assistance from the Google APIs team, but any further ideas are appreciated.

Comment: how about grabbing the `code` since it wasn't consumed anyway, and use it in a cURL call; this one works for me: `curl -v -d "grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&code=<code>" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the same error. It seems the problem is that `NET::OAuth2` sets the `authorization` header when exchanging authorization code for access token. If you remove this header everything works fine.
Check the `get_access_token` method in `Net::OAuth2::Profile::WebServer` module. The `authorization` header includes `client_id:client_secret` base64-encoded string. Apparently Google now treats this duplication as an error.

The right way of fixing this is to set the `secrets_in_params` parameter when creating `Net::OAuth2::Profile::WebServer` object. Look in the [Net::OAuth2::Profile](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/Net-OAuth2/lib/Net/OAuth2/Profile.pod) documentation for more details.

Comment: It's preferable to only pass the credentials in headers, when that option is supported by the server.

Answer (score 3):

Google [changed this behavior few days ago](http://www.cloudsponge.com/blog/stories/2015/04/14/gmail-oauth2-broken-and-fixed.html), so any OAuth2 library using Basic Auth headers **AND** body request parameters will start to see messages like

```
OAuth 2 parameters can only have a single value: client_id
```

or

```
OAuth 2 parameters can only have a single value: client_secret
```

So, you must now do **NOT** use both (the Auth headers and body request parameters) at the same time to send credentials to Google.

And according [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1), the preferable way to send credentials is through Auth headers (thanks @JanKrüger for alert me about this).

Comment: Not using the Auth header is actually probably not the best way to go. According to RFC 6749, section 2.3.1, support for the Authorization header is *required* in servers, and using fields in the request body is neither required nor recommended. All Google cares about at this point is that you use only *one* of these options, and if you want to stick more closely to the RFC, using *only* the `Authorization` header seems like the safer bet.

Comment: You're right @JanKrüger (and I upvoted your comment): I'll update my answer to make clear to use just one of them, preferably only Auth headers.